# Minimum number of records that can be stored in a B+ tree?

Tags: database, data-structures, b-tree

So the question I have to solve is this -

The size of block pointer (BP), keys (K), and record pointer (RP) is `100 bytes, 12 bytes, and 8 bytes long`. The total number of B+ tree levels is 3 for the organization of data files. Find the minimum
number of records in data files

Yes, the question doesn't state any block size. I have assumed it to be 1024

My attempt -

- So the order of the internal nodes can be given by `n*BP+(n-1)*K <= 1024`. That will give me a value for n
- For the leaf nodes, the order can be given as `L*(RP + K)+BP <= 1024`. This gives me a value of L
- The questions ask for the minimum number of records. For the root node, - we can have a minimum of 2 children.
- At the second level, we can have a minimum of n/2 children each.
- At the third level, we can have a minimum of L/2 records for each node.

Giving a total of `2*(n/2)*(L/2)`

> Is that the correct answer? It's a rather absurd question which I
> can't find an example similar to anywhere.